# Trying to surround the area produced by intersecting surfaces with a boundary line

Tags: graphics3d, regions, intersection

With MMA 12, I have a cone & sphere in 3D, that intersect. The area where they intersect I've managed to color (yellow), but I would like to surround that area with a more prominent line of a different color. I cannot figure out how to apply the boundary line.

Here is what I've managed so far:

```
Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalR], 1] = Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 3}}, 0.9];
Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalR], 2] = Sphere[{-2, 0, 0}, 3];
intersection = RegionIntersection[Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalR], 1], 
Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalR], 2]];

g = Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.12], Darker@Green, 
Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalR], 1]}, {Opacity[0.5], LightRed, 
Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalR], 2]}, Opacity[0.7], Yellow, 
EdgeForm[], MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[intersection], 2], 
Boxed -> False}];
Show[g, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boundary = RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion @ intersection,
  PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

```
Show[g, boundary, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks kglr! You know I played with the boundary command, but you know, I THINK I missed setting it equal to a variable and adding in show!! Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for!